# Pretty Url formattion in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Yii 2 application and I'd like to use some pretty URL. In my config file I already enable the pretty URL with the below rules:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    //'suffix' => '.html',
    'rules' => [
          '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
          '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+>/' => '<controller>/<action>/<slug>',
          '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/slug/<slug:\d+>/id/<id:\w+>/itmNo/<itmNo:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>/<slug>',
    ],
],
```

And the URL result is something like this `http://192.168.1.101/myproject/item?Id=mens-body-fitted-t-shirt-2018-summer-fashion-2&itmNo=82813720`

In the above URL `item` is the controller while `Id` and `itmNO` are queries, I'd like to get something like this below URL `http://192.168.1.101/myproject/item/mens-body-fitted-t-shirt-2018-summer-fashion-2/82813720`

The query name are replaced with `/`. How can I do this in Yii2 and still get the query in my controller to make the normal search?

My url creation looks like this

```
$myurl = \Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl(['/item','Id'=>$items['slug'].'-'.$items['product_id'],'itmNo'=>$items['item_number']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the most precise rule at the beginning:

```
'rules' => [
    '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/slug/<slug:\d+>/id/<id:\w+>/itmNo/<itmNo:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+>/' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
],
```

And create URL like this:

```
$myurl = \Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl([
    '/item/view',
    'id' => $items['product_id'],
    'slug' => $items['slug'],
    'itmNo' => $items['item_number'],
]);
```

Comment: i tried it but the url won't change, does that means i need to remove the query param from the url when i create it, my url creation looks like this   $myurl = \Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl(['/item','Id'=>$items['slug'].'-'.$items['product_id'],'itmNo'=>$items['item_number']]);

Comment: Please add this to your question, this is unreadable in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you are looking for is this rule:

```
> '<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>/<id:[\w\-]+>/<itmNo:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>'
```

In this case, you should indicate a controller name, id and itmNo as parameters. Don't forget to put this rule before more general ones. 
Sample query:

```
\Yii::$app->UrlManager->createUrl(['item/view','id'=>'slug'.'-'.'2', 'itmNo'=>'12313'])
```

read [this post](http://phpforgeeks.com/2018/07/20/customizing-routes-with-url-rules-in-yii2/) for better understanding